# Data cleaning this strange array format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, formatting

I’m new to python. I used python and Jupiter notebook and imported
Pandas & pypostal.

This is my code:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from postal.parser import parse_address
df = pd.read_csv("./file.csv").head(20)
df['LongAddr'].apply(parse_address)
df['parse_addr'] = df['LongAddr'].apply(parse_address)
df.to_csv('./new_file.csv', index=False)
print ("JOB DONE")
```

This is my file.csv:

---

```
customer_key    Company_Code    Name    Address_Type    LongAddr
0   CHIT000001  ZY1 Terry   CHI Nathan Road, Kowloon, Hong Kong
1   ENGT000002  BH6 Mary    ENG Flat E, 19/F, Blk A, Hilton building
2   RCHIT000003 EG9 John.G  CHI Marble Road Tai Koo Hong Kong
```

I had try output as cvs, json, xml.
However the file format wasn’t change any.
I have no clue with this format.
However, it turns out like this:

---

```
0  [(Hong Kong, state),(Kowloon, city),(Nathan Road, Road)]

1  [(flat E, unit), (19, level), (blk a hilton building, House)]

2  [(Hong Kong, state),(Tai Koo, city),(Marble Road, Road)]
```

All I want is .csv or .xlsx file
And output like this:

---

```
    customer_key, state, city, road, house, level, unit
0   CHIT000001, Hong Kong, Kowloon, Nathan Road,,
1   ENGT000002, ,,,Blk A Hilton building, 19/F, Flat E
2   RCHIT000003 Hong Kong, Tai Koo, Marble Road
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'tried output as ...'?  What code did you use?  You also need to be more specific about the data that you start with.   We need real details,.

Comment: just update the details! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create dictionary from resulting list of tuples by extracting State, city, road.
- Create new dataframe from dictionary and you can use to_csv() for exporting file.

  - use  respective file extension in to_csv()

**Please provide Sample Output next time. Steps to reproduce are not clear.**

Refer to below link:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Step updated!
Create dictionary from tuples can extracting State, city, road?
may you provided a code sample... it might be help. <3